# How to get summary totals on unique IDs using analytics?

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, analytics

My repeating table has duplicate ids but I want summary statistics on unique ids.

```
 Detail_id   code   book   tree
----------- ------ ------ ------
  1          BR54   COOK   PINE
  1          BR55   COOK   PINE
  1          BR51   COOK   PINE
  2          BR55   COOK   MAPL
  2          BR60   COOK   MAPL
  3          BR61   FORD   PINE
  3          BR54   FORD   PINE
  3          BR55   FORD   PINE
```

Here's my query which is also on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/889a8/15)

```
select count(case detail_book when 'COOK' THEN 1 else 0 end) as cook_total,
       count(case detail_book when 'FORD' THEN 1 else 0 end) as ford_total,
       count(case detail_tree when 'PINE' THEN 1 else 0 end) as pine_total,
       count(case detail_book when 'MAPL' THEN 1 else 0 end) as mapl_total
  from detail_records;
```

Desired results:

```
COOK_TOTAL FORD_TOTAL PINE_TOTAL MAPL_TOTL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
  2          1          2         1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need analytic functions here:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN detail_book = 'COOK' THEN detail_id END) AS cook_total
     , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN detail_book = 'FORD' THEN detail_id END) AS ford_total
     , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN detail_tree = 'PINE' THEN detail_id END) AS pine_total
     , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN detail_tree = 'MAPL' THEN detail_id END) AS mapl_total
  FROM detail_records;
```

The `CASE` statement returns NULL when the values don't match; those aren't counted.

[Updated SQL Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/889a8/46) By the way, in your query you were trying to match `detail_book` to `MAPL` when I think you wanted to match `detail_tree`, and my query reflects that.

Answer (score 4):

You could use analytic functions and an inline view to avoid the duplicate counting issue:

```
select sum(case when detail_book = 'COOK' and book_cntr = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cook_total,
       sum(case when detail_book = 'FORD' and book_cntr = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ford_total,
       sum(case when detail_tree = 'PINE' and tree_cntr = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as pine_total,
       sum(case when detail_tree = 'MAPL' and tree_cntr = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as mapl_total
  from (select d.*,
               row_number() over(partition by detail_book, detail_id order by detail_book, detail_id) as book_cntr,
               row_number() over(partition by detail_tree, detail_id order by detail_tree, detail_id) as tree_cntr
          from detail_records d) v
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/889a8/31/0

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on your example  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/889a8/29 which you can use to avoid the duplicate ids by getting the distinct ids for detail_book and detail_tree

Kindly check the result here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/889a8/44

```
        select sum(case detail_book
                           when 'COOK' THEN 1
                           else 0
                      end) as cook_total,
                sum(case detail_book
                           when 'FORD' THEN 1
                           else 0
                      end) as ford_total,
                sum(case detail_tree
                           when 'PINE' THEN 1
                           else 0
                      end) as pine_total,
                sum(case detail_tree
                           when 'MAPL' THEN 1
                           else 0
                      end) as mapl_total
        from  
        (select distinct detail_id,detail_book,detail_tree
         from
        detail_records);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query to get what you want just by removing the `else` clause:

```
select count(case detail_book when 'COOK' THEN 1 end) as cook_total,
       count(case detail_book when 'FORD' THEN 1 end) as ford_total,
       count(case detail_tree when 'PINE' THEN 1 end) as pine_total,
       count(case detail_book when 'MAPL' THEN 1 end) as mapl_total
from detail_records;
```

The default for `case` without an `else` is `NULL`, so the `count()` works.  Personally, I prefer `sum()` for this type of aggregation:

```
select sum(case when detail_book = 'COOK' THEN 1 else 0 end) as cook_total,
       sum(case when detail_book = 'FORD' THEN 1 else 0 end) as ford_total,
       sum(case when detail_tree = 'PINE' THEN 1 else 0 end) as pine_total,
       sum(case when detail_book = 'MAPL' THEN 1 else 0 end) as mapl_total
from detail_records;
```

Comment: It appears that this isn't what the user is trying to get at (though it was my initial interpretation).  I believe he's trying to count the distinct `detail_id` values for each of the conditions not trying to count the rows where each condition occurs.

Comment: Yes, Justin that is correct. Fiddle #29 in this thread (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/889a8/29) produces the correct number for the COOK_TOTAL. I was wanting to capture similiar queries into a single query.

Comment: worked with detail_id in my answer .. you can check if it works for you

Comment: @zundarz . . . Then you would add `detail_id` to the `select` and a `group by detail_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from analytical functions, I'd probably use an approach by first "flattening the table" (`union all`) and then *pivoting* the result:

```
select *
  from (
    select   detail_book i
    from     detail_records
    group by detail_id, detail_book
  union all
    select   detail_tree
    from     detail_records
    group by detail_id, detail_tree
)
  pivot(count(i) for i in ('COOK', 'FORD', 'PINE', 'MAPL'))
;
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60ccd/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (
select decode(detail_book,'FORD','FORD_TOTAL','COOK','COOK_TOTAL','MAPL','MAPL_TOTAL','PINE','PINE_TOTAL','OTHER') i, 
    count(distinct detail_id) j
from detail_records
group by detail_book
union all
select DECODE(detail_tree,'FORD','FORD_TOTAL','COOK','COOK_TOTAL','MAPL','MAPL_TOTAL','PINE','PINE_TOTAL','OTHER') i, 
    count(distinct detail_id) j
from detail_records
group by detail_tree
)
  pivot(sum(j) for i in ('COOK_TOTAL', 'FORD_TOTAL', 'PINE_TOTAL', 'MAPL_TOTAL','OTHER'))
;
```